SwiftUI - Restart app and apply new language after language selection
Problem
I'm trying to implement a language change feature in my SwiftUI app where when a user selects a new language, the app should restart and appear in the selected language. Currently, the language changes, but the UI doesn't fully update until the app is manually restarted.
Current Implementation

Language Selection View
struct LanguageSelectionView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.tabBarVisibility) var tabBarVisibility
    @StateObject private var localizationManager = LocalizationManager.shared
    @State private var selectedLanguage: Language
    @State private var showConfirmation = false
    @State private var languageToChange: Language?
    @AppStorage("restartKey") var restartKey: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // ... UI implementation ...
            .alert(isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Change Language"),
                    message: Text("The app needs to restart to change the language. Do you want to continue?"),
                    primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes")) {
                        if let language = languageToChange {
                            LocalizationManager.shared.setLanguage(language)
                            restartKey.toggle()  // This should trigger app restart
                        }
                    },
                    secondaryButton: .cancel()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


Localization Manager

class LocalizationManager: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = LocalizationManager()
    
    @Published var currentLanguage: Language {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currentLanguage.rawValue, forKey: "selectedLanguage")
            Bundle.setLanguageBundle(currentLanguage)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("LanguageChanged"), object: nil)
        }
    }
    
    @AppStorage("restartKey") var restartKey: Bool = false
    
    func setLanguage(_ language: Language) {
        guard language != currentLanguage else { return }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set([language.rawValue], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(language.rawValue, forKey: "selectedLanguage")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        
        currentLanguage = language
        
        // Attempt to trigger restart
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.restartKey.toggle()
        }
    }
}


Main App

@main
struct FaceAIEditApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject private var authManager = AuthenticationManager.shared
    @StateObject private var localizationManager = LocalizationManager.shared
    @AppStorage("restartKey") var restartKey: Bool = false

    init() {
        // Set initial language bundle on app launch

        // TabBar appearance configuration
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        tabBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                if authManager.isLoading {
                    // Show loading screen while checking auth state
                    ProgressView()
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
                } else {
                    MainTabView()
                        .id(restartKey) // This triggers view rebuild on language change
                        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: localizationManager.currentLanguage.rawValue))
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(authManager)
            .environmentObject(localizationManager) // Add localizationManager as environment object
            .environment(\.language, localizationManager.currentLanguage.rawValue)
            .onAppear {
                authManager.checkAndSignInAnonymously()
            }
        }
    }
}


Issue
When changing the language:

The language is saved correctly,
Some UI elements don't update,
Restarting the app manually updates it,


Question
How can I programmatically restart the entire app when the user selects a new language so that:

The app fully restarts,
All views are updated to the new language,
The app returns to its initial state (root view),
The change is smooth and user-friendly


I've Tried:

Using @AppStorage("restartKey") to trigger updates,
Posting notifications for language changes,
Force-updating views with the .id modifier,
Various UIApplication window manipulations


Environment

iOS 15+
Swift 5.5
SwiftUI
Xcode 14


I'm using the following extension:
import SwiftUI

public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func forceLocale(_ locale: String? ) -> some View {
        if let locale {
            self.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: locale))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

if you need to use OS's locale just call .forceLocale(nil)
usage:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestSwiftUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LanguageView()
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        }
    }
}

struct LanguageView: View {
    @State var identifier: String? = "en"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Ukrainian", action: {
                self.identifier = "uk"
            })
            
            Button("English", action: {
                self.identifier = "en"
            })
            
            Button("OS configured", action: {
                self.identifier = nil
            })
            
            Text("hello")
        }
        .forceLocale(identifier)
    }
}

no app restart needed to apply this setting.
Works well as you see:


Hi, I don't fully understand where I need to integrate, where I need to trigger.

at any place, better on main view of main window

just put into input parameter "en" to set English, "uk" to set ukrainian, "ru" to set russian, etc;  "nil" to set default OS language

I did it that way, in fact, according to the selected language, I give the languagemanager.currentLanguage.rawvalue value, when the user changes the language, that place is triggered by default, but there is no change when the language changes.

is your languagemanager is ObservableObject/ connected as ObservedObject/StateObject? is your currentLanguage is @Published ?

above I actually gave the localization manager that covers what you said

Try to create clean project and test it on clean project. I use this code in my own project ant it's works great :)

I couldn't find how to restart the app in swift ui how hard can it be anyway thank you I will try

updated answer with sample of usage. just copy-paste it into brand new project.

my system but you have localizable files you have static string in direct text

SwiftUI works with such localization system:) That's is native for SwiftUI.

thank you, I am thinking of converting the structure to this, so in this case, do you need localizable files or does the system automatically translate it itself?

ofc you need to localize by your own hands

On apps ive worked on, RootView would listen to notification center after user has selected a new language.
Then paired with id modifier, the rootview get rebuilt with the new language.
here is a sample code.
@State private var current: Language = .en

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        RootView()
        .id(current)
        .onAppear {
            current = //your saved language here, used when app first starts
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: YOUR_NOTIFICATION_KEY))) { _ in
            current = // set newly selected language here, when user has selected a new language
            // do any customize on views to retain customization on nav, etc..

        }
    }
}

